# Lightweight 'screentime' app for Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

I am currently running Lubuntu 18.04 and I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations for a lightweight app that records the total amount of time I spend on the screen every day. I have seen some applications that achieve this but many of them require you to manually start and stop a timer everytime you start working on the computer.

I am looking for an app that will is free, will automaticially startup and will count ALL screentime (a breakdown of how I the screentime was spent would be nice but isn't neccesary). Addittionaly, it would be nice if the screentime app would only record time when my moniter is on (so for example, if I'm listening to music but my moniter is off the app wouldn't record anything).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check [workflow](https://gitlab.com/cunidev/workflow). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) question for auto-starting applications on login.

Comment: Thanks @dlin for the response. When I run workflow, I need to have a terminal window constantly running. Is it possible to have workflow running without an open terminal window?

Comment: Run the process (e.g xyz) in the background by appending `&` after the command:

`xyz &`

If you want the process  to continue running in the background even after closing the terminal,  `nohup` will ignore the hup signal,

`nohup xyz &`

Comment: @dlin Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [ActivityWatch](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/releases)...works with all linux distros.

Requires:

- Python 3.6 or 3.7
- [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) `(python3 -m pip install poetry)`
- Node 12 or higher
- [Rust nightly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html)

For me, it runs just fine on my older machine (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS + Lubuntu Desktop.) I run it from a python virtual environment.

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

```
# In bash/zsh:

source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [workflow](https://gitlab.com/cunidev/workflow). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) Askubuntu question for auto-starting applications on login.